# What is the difference between cache and persist?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing, rdd

In terms of `RDD` persistence, what are the differences between `cache()` and `persist()` in spark ?

Answer (score 257):

With `cache()`, you use only the default storage level :

- `MEMORY_ONLY` for **RDD**
- `MEMORY_AND_DISK` for **Dataset**

With `persist()`, you can specify which storage level you want for both **RDD** and **Dataset**.

From the official docs:

> - You can mark an `RDD` to be persisted using the `persist`() or `cache`() methods on it.
> - each persisted `RDD` can be stored using a different `storage level`
> - The `cache`() method is a shorthand for using the default storage level, which is `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY` (store deserialized objects in memory).

Use `persist()` if you want to assign a storage level other than :

- `MEMORY_ONLY` to the **RDD**
- or `MEMORY_AND_DISK` for **Dataset**

Interesting link for the official documentation : [which storage level to choose](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#which-storage-level-to-choose)

Comment: Note that `cache()` now uses [MEMORY_AND_DISK](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache)

Comment: I don't think the above comment is correct. Reading the latest official documentation, using the link ahars provides aligns with the last bullet point... The cache() method is a shorthand for using the default storage level, which is StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY (store deserialized objects in memory).

Comment: @ximiki , `MEMORY_AND_DISK` is the default value only for Datasets. `MEMORY_ONLY` is still the default value for RDD

Comment: @user2596560 the comment is correct for the default cache value of the datasets. You are right for the RDD that still keep the MEMORY_ONLY default value

Answer (score 99):

> The difference between `cache` and `persist` operations is purely
> syntactic. cache is a synonym of persist or persist(`MEMORY_ONLY`), i.e.
> `cache` is merely `persist` with the default storage level `MEMORY_ONLY`

> But `Persist()`
> We can save the intermediate results in 5 storage levels.
>
> 1. MEMORY_ONLY
> 2. MEMORY_AND_DISK
> 3. MEMORY_ONLY_SER
> 4. MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER
> 5. DISK_ONLY

---

> /**    * Persist this RDD with the default storage level
> (`MEMORY_ONLY`).    */
> def persist(): this.type =
> persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
>
> /**    * Persist this RDD with the default storage level
> (`MEMORY_ONLY`).    */
> def cache(): this.type = persist()

see more details here...

---

*Caching or persistence are optimization techniques for (iterative and interactive) Spark computations. They help saving interim partial results so they can be reused in subsequent stages. These interim results as `RDD`s are thus kept in memory (default) or more solid storage like disk and/or replicated.
`RDD`s can be cached using `cache` operation. They can also be persisted using `persist` operation.*

> #`persist`, `cache`
>
> These functions can be used to adjust the storage level of a `RDD`.
> When freeing up memory, Spark will use the storage level identifier to
> decide which partitions should be kept. The parameter less variants
> `persist`() and `cache`() are just abbreviations for
> `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY).`

> ***Warning***: Once the storage level has been changed, it cannot be changed again!

---

#### Warning -Cache judiciously... see ([(Why) do we need to call cache or persist on a RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981359/why-do-we-need-to-call-cache-or-persist-on-a-rdd))

***Just because you can cache a `RDD` in memory doesn’t mean you should blindly do so. Depending on how many times the dataset is accessed and the amount of work involved in doing so, recomputation can be faster than the price paid by the increased memory pressure.***

***It should go without saying that if you only read a dataset once there is no point in caching it, it will actually make your job slower. The size of cached datasets can be seen from the Spark Shell..***

***Listing Variants...***

```
def cache(): RDD[T]
 def persist(): RDD[T]
 def persist(newLevel: StorageLevel): RDD[T]
```

***See below example :***

```
val c = sc.parallelize(List("Gnu", "Cat", "Rat", "Dog", "Gnu", "Rat"), 2)
     c.getStorageLevel
     res0: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel = StorageLevel(false, false, false, false, 1)
     c.cache
     c.getStorageLevel
     res2: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel = StorageLevel(false, true, false, true, 1)
```

[image: enter image here]

Note :
Due to the very small and purely syntactic difference between caching and persistence of `RDD`s the two terms are often used interchangeably.

See more visually here....

***Persist in memory and disk:***

[image]

#### Cache:

Caching can improve the performance of your application to a great extent.

[image]

---

*In general, it is recommended to use `persist` with a specific storage level to have more control over caching behavior, while cache can be used as a quick and convenient way to cache data in memory.*

Answer (score 51):

There is no difference.  From `RDD.scala`.

```
/** Persist this RDD with the default storage level (`MEMORY_ONLY`). */
def persist(): this.type = persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)

/** Persist this RDD with the default storage level (`MEMORY_ONLY`). */
def cache(): this.type = persist()
```

Answer (score 25):

Spark gives 5 types of Storage level

- `MEMORY_ONLY`
- `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`
- `MEMORY_AND_DISK`
- `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`
- `DISK_ONLY`

`cache()` will use `MEMORY_ONLY`. If you want to use something else, use `persist(StorageLevel.<*type*>)`.

By default `persist()` will
store the data in the JVM heap as unserialized objects.

Answer (score 6):

Cache() and persist() both the methods are used to improve performance of spark computation. These methods help to save intermediate results so they can be reused in subsequent stages.

The only difference between cache() and persist() is ,using Cache technique we can save intermediate results in memory only when needed while in Persist() we can save the intermediate results in 5 storage levels(MEMORY_ONLY, MEMORY_AND_DISK, MEMORY_ONLY_SER, MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER, DISK_ONLY).

Answer (score 5):

For **impatient**:

#### Same

Without passing **argument**, `persist()` and `cache()` are the same, with default settings:

- when `RDD`: MEMORY_ONLY
- when `Dataset`: MEMORY_AND_DISK

#### Difference:

Unlike `cache()`, `persist()` allows you to pass **argument** inside the bracket, in order to specify the level:

- `persist(MEMORY_ONLY)`
- `persist(MEMORY_ONLY_SER)`
- `persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)`
- `persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER )`
- `persist(DISK_ONLY )`

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Both cache() and persist() are 2 methods to persist cache or dataframe into memory or disk.
cache() method is shorthand for persist() with default storage level **MEMORY_ONLY**
while persist provide flexibility by allowing to specify the storage level explicitly

Spark RDD or Dataframe are lazily evaluated and sometimes we wish to use the same RDD or DATAFRAME multiple times.If we do naively , spark will recompute the RDD and all its dependencies each time we call an action on the RDD.
This is expensive if you are using your RDD or Dataframe iteratively.
To avoid computing an RDD multiple times, we can ask spark to persist the data.when we ask spark to persist an RDD or DATAFRAME, the nodes that computes the RDD or Dataframe store their partitions.

when you use persist instead cache(default MEMORY_ONLY) ,with persist there are different storage levels

| Level | Space Used | CPU Time | In Memory | On Disk | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MEMORY_ONLY | HIGH | LOW | Y | N |  |
| MEMORY_ONLY_SER | LOW | HIGH | Y | N | Data serialized to save space |
| MEMORY_AND_DISK | HIGH | MEDIUM | Some | Some | Splits to disk if data can't fit into worker node memory |
| MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER | LOW | HIGH | Some | Some | Same as MEMORY_AND_DISK, but write data in serialized format to save space |
| DISK_ONLY | LOW | HIGH | N | Y |  |