# Garbage Collection of RDDs

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a fundamental question in spark. Spark maintains lineage of RDDs to recalculate in case few RDDs get corrupted. So JVM cannot find it as orphan objects. Then how and when the garbage collection of RDDs happen?

Comment: Note that most RDDs are not stored at all. Check out the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981359/why-do-we-need-to-call-cache-or-persist-on-a-rdd/28983767

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The memory for RDD storage can be configured using

```
"spark.storage.memoryFracion" property.
```

If this limit exceeded, older partitions will be dropped from memory.

We can set it as a value between 0 and 1, describing what portion of executor JVM memory will be dedicated for caching RDDs. By default value is 0.66

Suppose if we have 2 GB memory, then we will get 0.4 * 2g memory for your heap and 0.66 * 2g for RDD storage by default.

We can configure Spark properties to print more details about GC is behaving:

Set `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` to include

```
“-verbose:gc -XX:-PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps”
```

In case your tasks slow down and you find that your JVM is garbage-collecting frequently or running out of memory, lowering "`spark.storage.memoryFracion`" value will help reduce the memory consumption.

For more details,have a look at below reference:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning

Comment: Typo: `spark.storage.memoryFraction`. This is value `spark.memory.fraction` in spark 2.x