# changing persistence level of an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have a question about [RDD's persistence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence). Let's say I have an `RDD` that's persisted `MEMORY_AND_DISK`, and I know that I now have enough memory space cleared up that I can force the data on disk into memory. Is it possible to tell spark to re-evaluate the open `RDD` memory and move that information?

Essentially I'm running into an issue with my `RDD` where I persist it and the entire `RDD` doesn't end up in memory until I query the `RDD` multiple times. This makes the first few runs extremely slow. One thing I'm hoping to try is to initially set the `RDD` to `MEMORY_AND_DISK` and then force the disk data back into memory.

Comment: By the way, I recommend you to read this post first [Differences between cache and persist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981359/why-do-we-need-to-call-cache-or-persist-on-a-rdd?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thank you @AlbertoBonsanto. I've also added some more specific information as to the problem I'm running into to give a better idea as to why I'm asking this question.

Comment: If you have enough memory available, then `MEMORY_AND_DISK` should not put any partitions onto disk in the first place.