# How can I do full outer join on multiple csv files (Linux or Scala)?

Tags: linux, scala, shell, csv, apache-spark

I have 620 csv files and they have different columns and data. For example:

```
//file1.csv
word, count1
w1, 100
w2, 200

//file2.csv
word, count2
w1, 12
w5, 22

//Similarly fileN.csv
word, countN
w7, 17
w2, 28
```

My expected output

```
//result.csv
word, count1, count2, countN
w1,    100,     12,    null
w2,    200 ,   null,    28  
w5,    null,    22,    null
w7,    null,   null,    17
```

I was able to do it in Scala for two files like this where `df1` is `file1.csv` and `df2` is `file2.csv`:

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("word"),"fullouter").show()
```

I need any solution, either in Scala or Linux command to do this.

Comment: Are you using Spark Dataframes?

Comment: yes, I am. Either spark or linux solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Spark you can read all your files as a `Dataframe` and store it in a `List[Dataframe]`. After that you can apply `reduce` on that `List` for joining all the dataframes together. Following is the code using three Dataframes but you can extend and use same for all your files.

```
//create all three dummy DFs
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("w1", 100), ("w2", 200))).toDF("word", "count1")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("w1", 12), ("w5", 22))).toDF("word", "count2")
val df3 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("w7", 17), ("w2", 28))).toDF("word", "count3")

//store all DFs in a list
val dfList: List[DataFrame] = List(df1, df2, df3)

//apply reduce function to join them together
val joinedDF = dfList.reduce((a, b) => a.join(b, Seq("word"), "fullouter"))

joinedDF.show()
//output
//+----+------+------+------+
//|word|count1|count2|count3|
//+----+------+------+------+
//|  w1|   100|    12|  null|
//|  w2|   200|  null|    28|
//|  w5|  null|    22|  null|
//|  w7|  null|  null|    17|
//+----+------+------+------+

//To write to CSV file
joinedDF.write
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("PATH_OF_CSV")
```

This is how you can read all your files and store it in a List

```
//declare a ListBuffer to store all DFs
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val dfList = ListBuffer[DataFrame]()

(1 to 620).foreach(x=>{
  val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load(BASE_PATH + s"file$x.csv")

  dfList += df
})
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to read 620 csv files in a loop? My file names are sequential.

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Comment: After running the reduce function for 8 minutes, I couldn't see the result of joinedDf or write it to csv. It shows java.lang.StackOverflowError. Any idea? The reduce instruction finished successfully.

Comment: where exactly are you getting SO. It may be because of large DAG as we are looping lots of DF. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909444/spark-java-lang-stackoverflowerror

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166875/discussion-between-abu-shoeb-and-vindev).