# how to cache random forest models in spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, random-forest

My platform is spark 2.1.0, using python language.

Now I have about 100 random forest multiclassification models ,I have saved them in the HDFS.There are 100 datasets saved in the HDFS too.
I want to predict the dataset using corresponding model.If the models and datasets are cache in memory,the predict will be more than 10 times faster.

But I do not know how to cache models because the model is not RDD or Dataframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Just `cache` the data, if it is ever reused outside prediction process, and if not you can even skip that.

`RandomForestModel` is a local object not backed by distributed data structures, there is no `DAG` to recompute, and prediction process is a simple, map-only job. Therefore model cannot be cached and even if it could, the operation would be meaningless.

See also [(Why) do we need to call cache or persist on a RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28981359/8371915)