# Calculating percentage of records having value > 2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I'm trying to get the percentage of records with value above 2.

Here is the code:

```
val seq = Seq(0, 1, 2, 3)
val scores = seq.toDF("value")
```

I'm able to achieve using the following steps.

```
val totalCnt = scores.count()
val morethan2 : Long = scores.filter(col("value") > 2).count()
val percent = morethan2.toFloat/totalCnt;
println(" percent is " + percent)
```

However, what is the best/optimized way to get this working in a single statement,
possibly using an aggregate function ?

Comment: What you are doing should already be quite optimal. However, depending on the data size and any transformations before the first `count`, it could help performance if you cache the data, see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981359/why-do-we-need-to-call-cache-or-persist-on-a-rdd

Comment: yes, i agree .. doing this in single line (as shown in answer below) seems to be an over-kill

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do at least one aggregation. Something like this.

```
val seq = Seq(0, 1, 2, 3)
val scores = seq.toDF("value")
  .withColumn("all", lit(1))
  .withColumn("morethan2", when(col("value") > 2, lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))
  .agg(sum(col("all")).as("count"), sum(col("morethan2")).as("morethan2count"))
  .withColumn("percent", col("morethan2count") / col("count"))

val percent = scores.take(1)(0).getAs[Double]("percent")
```

I hope it helps.