# How do I find all the textFile(s) loaded in the current spark context?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

For example, when I'm in the Spark Shell using PySpark, I might load a file into the spark context with the following command:

```
readme = sc.textFile("/home/data/README.md")
```

Then I can perform actions on this RDD(?) like below to count the number of lines in the file:

```
readme.count()
```

However what I want to know, is how can I get a list of all the `sc.textFile(s)` that I have loaded into the `sc` (spark context)?

For example there are commands to like below to get the all the configuration but it doesn't list all the textFile(s) that I've loaded.

```
sc._conf.getAll()
```

Is there any way to find all the textFiles that have been loaded into the spark context? A listing?

Answer (score 1):

SparkContext.textFile does not store anything in the Spark Context.
Take a look at the [sources](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala)

```
  /**
   * Read a text file from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any
   * Hadoop-supported file system URI, and return it as an RDD of Strings.
   * The text files must be encoded as UTF-8.
   *
```

You can always cache your RDD's in order to keep them in memory. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981359/why-do-we-need-to-call-cache-or-persist-on-a-rdd) explains caching mechanism.

If you want to keep track of files in your spark job, spark-submit provides the `--files` flag to upload files to the execution directories. If you have small files that do not change.

If you add your external files, spark-submit provides the `--files` flag

`spark-submit --files` your files will be uploaded to this HDFS folder: hdfs://your-cluster/user/your-user/.sparkStaging/application_1449220589084_0508

application_1449220589084_0508 is an example of yarn application ID!

In your spark application, you can find your files in 2 ways:

1- find the spark staging directory by below code: (but you need to have the hdfs uri and your username)

```
System.getenv("SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR");
```

> .sparkStaging/application_1449220589084_0508

2- find the complete comma separated file paths by using:

```
System.getenv("SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES");
```

> hdfs://yourcluster/user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1449220589084_0508/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar#**spark**.jar,hdfs://yourcluster/user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1449220589084_0508/your-spark-job.jar#**app**.jar,hdfs://yourcluster/user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1449220589084_0508/test_file.txt#test_file.txt