# Pyspark caches dataframe by default or not?

Tags: python, apache-spark, caching, pyspark

If i read a file in pyspark:

```
Data = spark.read(file.csv)
```

Then for the life of the spark session, the ‘data’ is available in memory,correct? So if i call data.show() 5 times, it will not read from disk 5 times. Is it correct? If yes, why do i need:

```
Data.cache()
```

Comment: I like to think about cache as a save point. In a scenario where you have done many aggregations that needs at least 5 minutes to finish, every time that you call `show()` will execute everything from zero, but if you cache your dataframe after the aggregation result, your `show()` command will execute almost instantly.

Comment: And you're thinking of a scenario where all the data will fit in the cluster's memory, but in cases where it won't fit and the data will be spilled onto the disk, if you don't do a filter and cache the result, every time that `show()` needs to be run, your application will move the data from disk to memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Why) do we need to call cache or persist on a RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981359/why-do-we-need-to-call-cache-or-persist-on-a-rdd)

Comment: So we cannot assign show() to a variable? X = data.show()? And then if we use x multiple times, the value is already cached in x,right?

Comment: @Victor `show()` only outputs a data sample. I would recommend you read about spark actions & transformations. Specially about lazy operations.

Comment: has nothing to do with pyspark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i read a file in pyspark:
> `Data = spark.read(file.csv)`
> Then for the life of the spark session, the ‘data’ is available in memory,correct?

No. Nothing happens here due to Spark lazy evaluation, which happens upon the first call to `show()` in your case.

> So if i call data.show() 5 times, it will not read from disk 5 times. Is it correct?

No. The dataframe will be re-evaluated for each call to `show`. Caching the dataframe will prevent that re-evaluation, forcing the data to be read from cache instead.