# SparkSQL serialized caching

Tags: caching, serialization, apache-spark-sql

Spark core supports both raw storage and serialized RDD caching.
This good article [explains](http://sujee.net/2015/01/22/understanding-spark-caching) this.
If you use `persist` - you may specify any of [levels](https://trongkhoanguyenblog.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/understand-the-storage-module-in-spark-core) of caching, but if you're use `cache` you may only use `MEMORY_ONLY` by default without serialization according this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870537/spark-what-is-the-difference-between-cache-and-persist).
Does anyone know how to use `MEMORY_ONLY_SER` caching in SparkSQL?
`cacheTable(my_table)` will cache with `MEMORY_ONLY` option, not with `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`, even if I have spark.storage.StorageLevel=MEMORY_ONLY_SER in spark environment by default.
My target is using serialized table caching from SparkSQL. Any ideas?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: yep, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

*Java:*

```
Option<String> tableName = new Some<String>("MyTable");
hiveContext.cacheManager().cacheQuery(hiveContext.table(tableName.get()),  tableName, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER());
```

*Scala:*

```
...cacheQuery(sqlContext.table(tableName), Some(tableName), MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Spark 1.3.0+ :
See [1.3.1 branch code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala)
See [1.5.1 branch code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala) (validate with`hiveContext.isCached(tableName)` )