# How to load a Spark model for efficient predictions

Tags: python, apache-spark, caching, pyspark, distributed-computing

When I build a Spark model and call it, the predictions take tens of ms to return.
However, when I save that same model, then load it, the predictions take much longer. Is there some sort of cache I should be using?

`model.cache()` after loading does not work, as the model is not an RDD.

This works great:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS
from pyspark import SparkContext
import time

sc = SparkContext()

# Some example data
r = [(1, 1, 1.0),
    (1, 2, 2.0),
    (2, 1, 2.0)]
ratings = sc.parallelize(r)
model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, 1, seed=10)

# Call model and time it
now = time.time()
for t in range(10):
    model.predict(2, 2)

elapsed = (time.time() - now)*1000/(t+1)

print "Average time for model call: {:.2f}ms".format(elapsed)

model.save(sc, 'my_spark_model')
```

Output: `Average time for model call: 71.18ms`

If I run the following, the predictions take much more time:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import MatrixFactorizationModel
from pyspark import SparkContext
import time

sc = SparkContext()

model_path = "my_spark_model"
model = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, model_path)

# Call model and time it
now = time.time()
for t in range(10):
    model.predict(2, 2)

elapsed = (time.time() - now)*1000/(t+1)

print "Average time for loaded model call: {:.2f}ms".format(elapsed)
```

The output: `Average time for loaded model call: 180.34ms`

For BIG models, I'm seeing prediction times over 10 seconds for a single call after loading a saved model.

Answer (score 3):

In short: *No*, it doesn't seem to be something that could cache the whole model, since it's not an RDD.

---

Yu can try to use [cache()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=cache#pyspark.RDD.cache), but you cannot cache the model itself, because it is not an RDD, so try this:

```
model.productFeatures().cache()
model.userFeatures().cache()
```

It is recommended to [unpersist()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=unpersist#pyspark.Broadcast.unpersist) them after you don't need it, especially if you handle really big data, since you will want to protect your job from out-of-memory errors.

Of course, you could use `persist()` instead of `cache()`; you might want to read: [What is the difference between cache and persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870537/what-is-the-difference-between-cache-and-persist)

---

Remember that Spark does *transformations* **lazily**, so when you load the model *nothing really happens*. It needs an *action* to trigger actual work (i.e. when you really use the `model` then Spark will attempt to load it, causing you to experience some latency, versus on having it in memory).

<sub>Also note that: `cache()` is lazy, so you can use `RDD.count()` explicitly to load into memory.</sub>

---

Experiments' output:

```
Average time for model call: 1518.83ms
Average time for loaded model call: 2352.70ms
Average time for loaded model call with my suggestions: 8886.61ms
```

By the way, after the loading of the model, you should receive this kind of warnings:

```
16/08/24 00:14:05 WARN MatrixFactorizationModel: User factor does not have a partitioner. Prediction on individual records could be slow.
16/08/24 00:14:05 WARN MatrixFactorizationModel: User factor is not cached. Prediction could be slow.
```

But what if I do the count trick? I won't get any gain at all, in fact I will be slower:

```
...
model.productFeatures().cache()
model.productFeatures().count()
model.userFeatures().cache()
model.userFeatures().count()
...
```

Output:

```
Average time for loaded model call: 13571.14ms
```

Without the `cache()`, keeping the `count()`s, I got:

```
Average time for loaded model call: 9312.01ms
```

Important Note: Timing performed in real-world cluster, where the nodes are given to important jobs, so my toy example may have been preempted during the experiments. Moreover, the communications cost may dominate.

So, if I were you I would conduct the experiments myself too.

---

In conclusion, there doesn't seem to be any other mechanism available from Spark on caching your model, other than that.

Comment: Thanks @gsamaras. `cache()` was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately, within PySpark, models cannot be cached. Here's the error: `AttributeError: 'MatrixFactorizationModel' object has no attribute 'cache''`

Comment: You didn't mention it. :/ That happens because model is not an RDD. cache() works only on RDDs. BTW, nice question. Did you try `model.productFeatures().cache()` and/or `model.userFeatures.cache()`? Since these two are paired RDDs.

Comment: @zbinsd damn it,  thought I had fixed that already! Check my updated answer! ;)