# How to decide when to use spark sql cache or persists?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Me using spark-sql for data migration project.
So how should I implement stage area in spark ?
when to use spark sql cache or persists?
any real time use cases ?

~Sha

Answer (score -1):

Similarly to `RDD` ([What is the difference between cache and persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26870537)) the only difference between `cache` and `persist` is ability to set non-default storage mode.

There is one important difference though. Unlike in `RDD` API, where `cache` uses `MEMORY_ONLY`, `Dataset` counterpart uses `MEMORY_AND_DISK`.