# How do I collect all those rows/records from a dataframe which didn't pass this filter condition. any inbuilt methods or else?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am still learning Scala/Spark.

I am working on filtering of the dataframe based on some conditions or values.

`df.filter()` - works well but I also want to store all those rows/records in another dataframe which does not pass this filter condition.

I tried to search on net but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As it's not clear what's desired and you've accepted the answer on just using filter, it may be useful to have a look at (disclaimer as I'm the author) [Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/), it allows an audit trail and management of multiple filter conditions.  It doesn't get past the need to filter per below if you don't want to store the resulting rows together, but it could add some more flexibility and control.

Answer (score 0):

A naive option is to create two DFs:

```scala
val df = ???

val df1 = df.filter(condition)
val df2 = df.filter(!condition)
```

This would compute `df` twice though. Depending on your use case, it can be acceptable or not.

---

An alternative is to cache `df` so that it's computed only once.

```scala
val df = ???

val dfCached = df.cache

val df1 = dfCached.filter(condition)
val df2 = dfCached.filter(!condition)
```

*There are multiple options for caching. It can be in memory or stored on disk. I let the reader check documentation about this.*

See also [What is the difference between cache and persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870537/what-is-the-difference-between-cache-and-persist)

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't tell us much: what did not work? Maybe you may edit your original post with more requirements and what you plan to do with the 2 DFs afterwards if this naive solution doesn't fit. (A new question might be better as this one is considered answered though).